# Can multiple threads modify the same private member of a C++ object by calling the same method of that object?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
file1.hpp:
class KMeans {
 public:
  KMeans();
  virtual ~KMeans();
  void Start();
 private:
  std::atomic<int32_t> thread_counter_;
  std::unique_ptr<boost::barrier> process_barrier_;
  // ============ PS Tables ============
  petuum::Table<float> centres_;
  int examples_per_batch_;
  int examples_per_thread_;
};

file2.cpp:
int main(){
  KMeans kmeans;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(FLAGS_num_app_threads);
  for (auto& thr : threads) {
    thr = std::thread(&KMeans::Start, std::ref(kmeans));
  }

}
```

In file2 the `main()` creates several threads by

```
std::thread(&KMeans::Start, std::ref(kmeans));
```

The `KMeans::Start` method needs access to the private field of `KMeans` class. My question is: Do these threads operate on the same `KMeans` object, or on different objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They operate on the same instance, because you pass `kmeans` by reference (using `std::ref`). This would be very easy to confirm by printing `this` in `Start()`:

```
KMeans::Start()
{
    std::cout << this << std::endl;
}
```

If you didn't want them to operate on the same member, you could use a copy of `kmeans`:

```
std::thread(&KMeans::Start, kmeans);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helps!